# Unity Facebook WebGL build... Does this work or not?!?! Getting conflicting answers

Tags: unity, facebook, build-process, unity-webgl

[So here is the facebook documentation..](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/unitywebgl#upload)

It seems to be saying you can output a Facebook WebGL build from Unity and upload it.
It does not work for me, I get this message when I upload.

"Games must reference one of our supported SDKs via our CDN."

Theres also this thread, with people saying it is not supported.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/facebook-instant-games-support-html5.499198/

Yet the latest version of Unity has a WebGL option when building to Facebook platform.
[image]

What is going on?
Does or doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone comes across this and was confused like I am-

Facebook no longer separates Web Hosting from Instant Games; to upload a build, upload it under Instant Games/Web Hosting, then disable "Use Instant Games" in the Instant Games settings to have a facebook web game, not instant game.

If you run across the "Games must reference one of our supported SDKs via our CDN." error, I found a weird solution - make a test app, then upload the build under that test app. Go back to the main app and your build will be there.

Comment: This worked for me! Thnx

P.S. love your profile pic xD

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a reference to the sdk in index.html file.

src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.3.js

Adding the above line into you index.html file will solve the issue.(Add the script tag    ).

Answer (score -2):

BLeh forget it... Facebooks site is just a mess. I was getting 'Instant games' and 'webhosting' mixed up

Comment: If you edit this answer to include a little more information on what each one is, and how to choose the right one, you may help the next person to come along who's having the same confusion.